# Pycharm iPython console not working with remote host

Tags: python, console, ipython, pycharm

I have set up PyCharm 2016.2.3 on Win10 to work with remote Ubuntu 16.04 server. Everything works great - running, debugging, even X11 forwarding (with Putty).

However, I am unable to run remote iPython console (if iPython is disabled in Settings, regular console works).

I  get following error message:

```
Error:Console process terminated with error:
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/prompt_toolkit/interface.py", line 81, in __init__
self.input = input or StdinInput(sys.stdin)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/prompt_toolkit/input.py", line 67, in __init__
assert self.stdin.isatty()
AssertionError
```

On the server I am running Python 3.5 with iPython (5.1.0)

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patch has been issued (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20732) and will be fixed in latest PyCharm version.